# Rails Hyphen in form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, hyphenation

In the below form I need the :data_progression to be data-progression in the HTML.

Hyphen instead of underscore.

How do I achieve this? Have looked around but haven't come across a clear explanation.

```
<%= form_for @contact_form, :html => {:id => "myform"} do |f| %>
<p>
<%= f.text_field :name, :class => "first_name", :id => "first_name", :data_progession => "" %>Name  &amp Number<br />
<%= f.text_field :email, :class => "email" %>E-mail<br />
<%= f.text_area :message, :class => "message", :placeholder => "Your Message Here*" %><br />
<%= f.submit "Send", :class => "button" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use data attributes in a Rails helper, the current preferred method is to use a data hash as so:

```
<%= f.text_field :name, :class => "first_name", :id => "first_name", :data => { :progression => "" } %>Name  &amp Number<br />
```

That should give you the hyphen like you desire. Also, anything in the data hash should convert to hyphens to conform with html customs.

Comment: You should also be able to use strings as keys: `"data-progression" => ""

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm not mistaken (didn't test myself now), but it should be e.g.

`f.text_field :name, :class => "first_name", :id => "first_name", :data => { :progession => "" }`